# Exercise on Orthogonal Projection

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, orthogonality, projection

For an exercise, I need to investigate the orthogonal projection in more detail. I know that this has probably been discussed many times here, I am though interested in whether my explanations suffice and in particular in Tasks 3 and 4. Concretely, the exercise states :

Let $\mathcal{M}$ be a closed subspace of a Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ and let

$\mathcal{M}^{\bot} = \{x \in \mathcal{H} : \langle x, y \rangle_{\mathcal{H}} = 0 , \forall y \in \mathcal{M} \}$

be the corresponding orthogonal space, i.e. the space of all vectors $x \in \mathcal{H}$ which are perpendicular to all vectors $y \in \mathcal{M}$. Then, it can be shown that every vector $x \in \mathcal{H}$ has a unique decomposition $x = x_{\mathcal{M}} + x_{\bot}$ with $x_{\mathcal{M}} \in \mathcal{M}$ and $x_{\bot} \in M^{\bot}$. Based on this decomposition, one defines the mapping $P_{\mathcal{M}} : \mathcal{H} \rightarrow \mathcal{H}$ by

$P_{\mathcal{M}}(x) = x_{\mathcal{M}} ,  x \in \mathcal{H}$

Tasks :

1. Is $P_{\mathcal{M}}$ linear?
2. What is the range $R(P_{\mathcal{M}})$ and the nullspace $\mathcal{N}(P_{\mathcal{M}})$ of this mapping?
3. Determine the norm of $P_{\mathcal{M}}$
4. Verify that
   $P_{\mathcal{M}}(x) = \arg \min_{y \in \mathcal{M}} \left\| x - y \right\|_{\mathcal{H}}$
   , i.e. $\hat{x} = P_{\mathcal{M}} x$ is the vector that minimizes $\left\| x - y \right\|_{\mathcal{H}}$ among all $y \in \mathcal{M}$.

**My thoughts so far :**

1. It is easy to see that $P_{\mathcal{M}}(\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2) = (\alpha x_1 + \beta x_2)_{\mathcal{M}} = \alpha \cdot (x_1)_{\mathcal{M}} + \beta \cdot (x_2)_{\mathcal{M}}$ via the properties of the linear subspace $\mathcal{M} \subset \mathcal{H}$.
2. The orthogonal projection is a projection for which the range and nullspace are orthogonal subspaces. Hence, we have that the range $R(P_{\mathcal{M}}) = \mathcal{M}$ as defined above. Consequently, the nullspace must be $\mathcal{N}(P_{\mathcal{M}}) = M^{\bot}$.
3. The norm can be derived as follows. Consider $\left\| Px \right\|^2 = |\langle Px, Px \rangle| = |\langle x, Px \rangle| \leq \left\| x \right\| \cdot \left\| Px \right\|$. Accordingly, we have that $\left\| P \right\| = \frac{\left\| Px \right\|}{\left\| x \right\|} \leq 1$
4. By inspection, it becomes clear that $y$ is the solution to the problem, since perpendicularity implies that the scalar product in the corresponding space is zero. But how to verify that??

I would appreciate a quick look at my results as well as an intuition as how to verify task 4. Any help is appreciated :-)

Comment: $P$ is clearly linear and self-adjoint and projection: $P^* = P = P^2$. So $||P|| = ||P^* P|| = ||P||^2$, so $||P|| \in \{0,1\}$.
$M = R(P) = R(P^*) = N(P)^\perp$, so $M^\perp = (N(P)^\perp)^\perp = N(P)$.
$||x-y||^2 = ||Px-y||^2+||(I-P)x||^2$, by Pythagoras.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2. You haven't checked that $P$ is a projection (i.e. $P^2 = P$) so you'll need to prove this if you want to use properties of projections. If I were you I would just prove the results directly
   $$ \text{Im } P = \{ P(x_M + x_\perp) = x_M : x_M \in M, x_\perp \in M^\perp \} = M $$
   $$ \ker P = \{ x = x_M + x_\perp: x_M = 0, x_\perp \in M^\perp,x_M \in M\} = M^\perp$$
3. $\left\| P \right\| = \frac{\left\| Px \right\|}{\left\| x \right\|}$ is not how the operator norm is defined. Also $\Vert P\Vert \leq 1$ is not sufficient to determine the norm of $P$ you must still show that $\Vert P \Vert \geq 1$ to deduce that $\Vert P \Vert  = 1$. You're better off using the identity $P^2 = P$ for this part
4. Hint : use the fact that if $v $ and $w$ are orthogonal then
   $$ \Vert v+w \Vert^2 = \Vert v \Vert^2 + \Vert w \Vert^2$$
   (this is just Pythagoras' theorem). Use this with $x - y = (x_M - y) + x_\perp$

Comment: The equality $|\langle Px, Px \rangle| = |\langle x, Px \rangle|$ is correct.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable notes! I have made some adjustments and incorporated the statements and will post subsequently as an edit in my question. I think this should be it now. Would be very nice if someone could review it :-)

Answer (score 0):

**Edit :**

Thanks to the comments from @Digitallis and @psl2Z, this should be sufficient answers to tasks 3. and 4. :

**To answer 3.** , we derive the operator norm as follows.

First, consider that

$\left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} x \right\|^2 = |\langle P_{\mathcal{M}} x, P_{\mathcal{M}} x \rangle| = |\langle x, P_{\mathcal{M}} x \rangle| \leq \left\| x \right\| \cdot \left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} x \right\|$

from which follows that
$\left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} \right\| \leq 1$

Second, consider using the identity $P_{\mathcal{M}}^2 = P_{\mathcal{M}}$ that

$\left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} x \right\| = \left\| P_{\mathcal{M}}^2 x \right\| = \left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} (P_{\mathcal{M}} x) \right\| \leq \left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} \right| \cdot \left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} x \right\|$

from which we evidently have that

$\left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} \right\| \geq 1$

Accordingly, we must have for the operator norm of the orthogonal projection that

$\left\| P_{\mathcal{M}} \right\| = 1$

**To answer 4.** , we use the fact that if $v$ and $w$ are orthogonal, then it follows via Pythagoras' theorem that

$\left\| v + w \right\|^2 = \left\| v \right\|^2 + \left\| w \right\|^2$

Accordingly, we can reformulate this expression using $x = x_{\mathcal{M}} + x_{\bot}$ and $y \in \mathcal{M}$ as follows

$\left\| x - y \right\|^2 = \left\| (x_{\mathcal{M}} - y) + x_{\bot} \right\|^2 = \left\| (x_{\mathcal{M}} - y)\right\|^2 + \left\| x_{\bot} \right\|^2$

Here, it is obvious that $v =  (x_{\mathcal{M}} - y)$ and $w = x_{\bot}$ are perpendicular. Now, recall the definition of $P_{\mathcal{M}}$ as

$P_{\mathcal{M}}(x) = x_{\mathcal{M}} , x \in \mathcal{H}$

Accordingly, we obtain $x_{\mathcal{M}}$ for the input $x$ exactly when minimizing

$\left\| x - y \right\|^2 = \left\| (x_{\mathcal{M}} - y) + x_{\bot} \right\|^2 = \left\| (x_{\mathcal{M}} - y)\right\|^2 + \left\| x_{\bot} \right\|^2$

w.r.t. the variable $y$. Further, the solution does not change when taking the square root of this expression. Accordingly, we obtain the statement

$P_{\mathcal{M}}(x) = \arg \min_{y \in \mathcal{M}} \left\| x - y \right\|_{\mathcal{H}}$

Comment: Did you mean to write $y$ instead of $x$ in "We obtain $x_M$ for the input $x$ exactly when minimising ..."

Comment: should be $y = x_{\mathcal{M}}$ since $y$ is the variable and later also in the statement